# Parse XML in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am partway through pasing xml in python but have run into a bit of a stumbling block with the xml I am trying to render I am using `xml.dom.minidom` and I can get the xml no worries that bit is easy just the place I am getting it from is messing about with weird syntax what I am getting is something like this.

```
<enclosure name="link1" url="http://google.co.uk/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```

What I am strugling to do with the code bellow is get a way to extract the string from the url attribute I have googled and found nothing. I thought someone with more experience in xml would have an idea about how to do this. Bellow is the code I have so far for this section

```
files = urllib2.urlopen(x)
data = files.read()
files.close()

dom = parseString(data)

xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('enclosure')[0].toxml()
print xmlTag
```

Comment: That looks more like HTML you're trying to parse - are you sure you're parsing XML?

Comment: yea I am sure it's XML it's a rss feed containing videos. I know the difference between HTML and XML. I used the name link as an example it's actually called enclosure. All the other elements are the same as XML

Comment: Heres what is at the top of the doc if you don't believe me `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: No worries - not like I didn't believe you - just that your original post had enough ambiguity to require clarification - and someone had to ask for that :)

Comment: Yeah suppose looking at it again I can see that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

xml = '<enclosure name="link1" url="http://google.co.uk/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />'
parsed_xml= BeautifulSoup(xml)
print parsed_xml.enclosure['url']
```

**OUTPUT**

```
http://google.co.uk/vid.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks mate didn't realise you could use beautiful soup that way.